# Trigger DAG for every file inside directory

Tags: python, triggers, airflow

Very new to airflow so bare with me. I'm currently using a filesensor to trigger a DAG to process a file within a directory. Problem is, I need to iterate and run the DAG for each individual file that's in a directory. Any suggestions?

```
) as dag:
waiting_for_file = FileSensor(
    task_id = 'waiting_for_file',
    filepath = base_path,
    # file sensor will look for file every 30 seconds
    poke_interval = 30,
    timeout = 60 * 2 # 2 minutes
) 

trigger_target = TriggerDagRunOperator(
    task_id = 'idk_what_im_doing',
    trigger_dag_id = 'ETL_process',
    execution_date = '{{ ds }}',
    reset_dag_run = True, 
    # wait_for_completion = True
)
```